# While loop not properly breaking

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate a line of text that does not exceed a certain number of syllables in JavaScript running in Node. I have made the following function using a library syllable:

```
function generateLine(maxSyllableLength) {
    let line = "";
    let numSyllables = 0;

    /* generate line 
    while current number of syllables is less than the max:
        get a new word
        if the new word's syllables + the current number of syllables is less than the max:
            add the new word to the line
            add the new word's syllables to syllable count
    */
    while(numSyllables <= maxSyllableLength) {
        let word = randomWord();
        if(syllable(word) + numSyllables < maxSyllableLength) {
            line += word;
            numSyllables += syllable(word);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect it to break but it just runs forever and stalls Firefox when executed on Node. For reference, `syllable(word)` returns the number of syllables in `word`

`randomWord()` returns a, well, random word (a lot of them) and I am testing the function with `maxSyllableLength` = 5.

Full code:

```
var buzzwords = require('buzzwords')
var syllable = require('syllable')

/* constants for syllables in a haiku */
const LINE_ONE_THREE = 5;
const LINE_TWO = 7;

export default function Buzz() {
    /* generate line 1 */
    let lineOne = generateLine(5);
    console.log(lineOne); // debug

    /* render */
    return (
        <p id="test">{test}</p>
    );
}

function randomWord() {
    /* index of word we will pick out */
    let index = Math.floor((Math.random() * buzzwords.length) + 1); 

    /* pull a word from the array using that index */
    let word = buzzwords[index];
    return word;
}

function generateLine(maxSyllableLength) {
    let line = "";
    let numSyllables = 0;

    /* generate line 
    while current number of syllables is less than the max:
        get a new word
        if the new word's syllables + the current number of syllables is less than the max:
            add the new word to the line
            add the new word's syllables to syllable count
    */
    while(numSyllables <= maxSyllableLength) {
        let word = randomWord();
        if(syllable(word) + numSyllables < maxSyllableLength) {
            line += word;
            numSyllables += syllable(word);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough information on what the numbers are. Could you provide an example?

Comment: show us your complete code

Comment: syllable(word) is always greater max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This endless loop seems to have a pretty simple explanation.

Assuming the following scenario:

- `maxSyllableLength` is set to `4`.
- `randomWord()` always returns a random word of 2 syllables.

The first iteration `numSyllables` will be `0`, matching the criteria to stay in the *while*-loop. `syllable(word) + numSyllables` will be `2`, matching the *if* criteria. The `line` is extended with a random word and `numSyllables` is incremented accordingly.

The second iteration `numSyllables` will be `2`, matching the criteria to stay in the *while*-loop. `syllable(word) + numSyllables` will be `4`, not matching the *if* criteria. The loop starts over since the *while*-loop criteria still matches. Since nothing is changed the *while*-loop will go infinite at this point.

Summarized your *while*-loop will be infinite because `numSyllables` must be smaller or equal to the max, but can never exceed the max because `syllable(word) + numSyllables` must be lower than the max to increment the current values.

Comment: Ahhhh, there we go. Thanks. That's what happens when you try and write code on little sleep I suppose - I meant to do ```while(numSyllables != maxSyllableLength)```

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
if(syllable(word) + numSyllables < maxSyllableLength)
```

if numSyllables goes over the amount allocated, the loop needs to break, because now numSyllables is not able to go over maxSyllableLength so you need to not put the line

```
numSyllables += syllable(word)
```

within the if statement.

Comment: I am saying that the line should not be in the if statement.

Comment: where did you put the line, directly below the if statement?